# matcher for findHomography from a list of points (of different lengths) rather than an image

Tags: python, opencv, matcher, homography

**Tl;dr;**
I want to use a `bf.matcher`, without using sift, surf or any of these methods. I just have two sets of points (of different lengths) that I'd like to match.
Any idea how to do it?

---

Hello,

I've got a photo in which I've detected the approximate centers of some distinct objects (with a custom method). *I don't detect all of them, and there are a few outliers.*
I know the position of these objects in the real world.

Now, I would like to **match these approximate positions to the real world positions**. The final goal would be to set the real world coordinate system (in meters) in my image (in px).
I guess I just want to find a homography between my two sets, right?

```
# Let's say for example that my set of image coordinates is:
Xim = [735, 760, 610, 462]
Yim = [-685, -631, -485, -319]

# And that they have to be matched with:
Xreal = [0.75, 0.875, 0.125, -0.625, -0.125, 0.25]
Yreal = [1.625, 1.875, 2.625, 3.5, 4.25, 4.75]
```

If I want to use the opencv function `cv2.findHomography`, I need to have the same amount of points in the two sets. So I was going to test every possible combination of points (`6 choose 4 = 15 here`), calculate their homography matrices, and choose the one with the least distortion.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import cv2

# I need 4 points in both sets, so I'm trying all combinations:
Xreal_test=[]; Yreal_test = []
combin = itertools.combinations(np.arange(len(Xreal)),len(Xim))
for k,c in enumerate(combin):
    Xreal_test = Xreal_test + [[Xreal[list(c)[i]] for i in range(len(list(c)))]]
    Yreal_test = Yreal_test + [[Yreal[list(c)[i]] for i in range(len(list(c)))]]


# Formatting the sets that way cv2.findHomography wants them, and calculate homography
H=[]
pts_xim = np.array([[Xim[x],Yim[x]] for x in range(len(Xim))])
for i in range(len(Xreal_test)):
    pts_xreal = np.array([[Xreal_test[i][x],Yreal_test[i][x]] for x in range(len(Xim))])
    # Calculate homography
    h, _ = cv2.findHomography(pts_xreal, pts_xim, cv2.RANSAC)
    H = H + [h]
```

And that's it!
But of course, I have much more than these points, and **trying all combinations would be extremely resource consuming** (if not plain stupid).

So instead of calculating an homography for all possible combinations, I'd like to use something slightly less "brute-force", for example with `bf.Matcher()`.

Here is where I am now. I know how to do it with images, but not with a set of points (which should be easier). Finding homographies from images can be done this way:

```
img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)         
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)
src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

h, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
```

`kp, des = surf.detectAndCompute(img,None)` gives two outputs, `keypoints` and `descriptors`. I don't need to use surf (or sift, or orb) for my problem, however I need to feed bf.matcher with the descriptor. 
**Any idea how to do it with a set of predefined points ?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to use something _"less brute force"_ and use a Brute Force Matcher? :)

Comment: I thought that the fact it uses a descriptor made it somehow less brute force? I must say I'm not quite clear on how it works though.  

I just know that the brute force matcher seems to still work well with more than 50 points to match. On the other hand, if I try all combinations, let's say I have for example 20 detected points to match among 40 real world points, it makes 137 846 528 820 combinations to test. It looked astronomous to me, is it not?  

Or else, I could use a flann matcher, but I have the same problem: it needs to be fed with a descriptor, and I don't have any.

Comment: Just use your list of corresponding control points in the image and on the ground and do a simple perspective transform to warp one image to match the ground. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: The problem is that if I want to perform the `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_xim,pts_xreal)`, I still need to have the same number of points in both images. So I would need to do the perspective transform for all combinations of image points with real points, which is huge... Plus, I believe that in my case using `findHomography` is better, since unlike in `getPerspectiveTransform` I don't need to have the points in the right order.